# Python, installing clarifai --> VS14.0 link.exe failed with exit status 1158

Tags: python, visual-c++, command-line, clarifai

I've got a fresh installation of Python 3.6 + Selenium and now want to install Clarifai 2.0.21.

The following command is failing:

```
python -m pip install clarifai==2.0.21
```

At first it requested VC++ 14.0 but I had 14.1 (with VS2017),
so I installed VC++2015 BuildTools which has 14.0. This worked partly until creating the library.

I got the new error as next:

> Generating code
>   Finished generating code
>   LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
>      error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

Any idea if there's something missing in my installation?
Thank You

Answer (score 154, accepted):

I had a similar  problem today, and I solved it referring to

[Visual Studio can't build due to rc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe?newreg=f00ac10c2a4448ceb438f258e5c229a4).

To fix the issue, do next steps:

1. Add this to your `PATH` environment variables:

   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64`
2. Copy these files `rc.exe` & `rcdll.dll` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin`

In newer Windows these files might also be in the highest version: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.VERSION\x86`

Comment: My goodness this issuess... Anyway doing just step2 was enough for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @joe, thanks a lot, following from #2 helped me too. I had a problem installing Twisted as a dependency for Scrapy

Comment: These steps also worked for me when I was trying to install oscodepoint and had the same error

Comment: You could also just APPEND C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86 to your PATH variable with: set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\

Comment: While this answer may work, it feels wrong because it's mixing up x86 and x64 specific files.

Comment: I am looking to try this, as I was having a Link1158 error for python build. I am unable to find rc.exe and rcdll.dll in the location listed here.

Comment: These also worked on Cython failing `setup.py` builds

Comment: Worked for me too! Tried to install mod-wsgi with PIP. Thanks.

Comment: I have Windows 10 and `Windows Kits` contains only `10` folder. The `rc.exe` and `rcdll.dll` are available under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\VERSION_NUMBER\x86` and multiiple VERSION_NUMBER folders are present. I copied these two files from the folder with the highest version number and it worked.

Comment: Thanks joe, worked for me on Python 3.6.1 in Windows 10 with MS Visual Studio Build Tools 2019

Comment: Commenting to add that this answer also helped me solve `link.exe failed with exit code 1327`

Comment: This is priceless. But the question is, How the hell can we know this? And solve such errors!!!!

Answer (score 16):

I had the very same problem when using **PIP / Python 3.5** and **Visual Studio 2017** while installing librosa using **pip** (and it's dependency resampy)

Solved the problem using the **Visual Studio 2017 Developer prompt** and running pip install from there.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I have VC 14 and its not working, also this question was for vc 2015, not 2017
Thanks.

Comment: And you tried using your versions developer prompt? You did not state that in your question. If so, you should add it into your question.

Comment: easiest solution .. Thanks :D

Answer (score 10):

In case this helps someone. The original problem didn't occur for me with a baseline VS2015. I now see the same problem with the LNK1158 error. I surmise because I'm now using VS2015 Update 2, which uses rc.exe from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64".
The solution is similar to another answer. It is to either copy or take a symlink of rc.exe and rcdll.dll from:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64
```

to

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64
```

Comment: thanks ! the comment above didn't work and your did ( for me )