# OpenSlide-python install in windows10

Tags: python, openslide

Plateform:

win10 home

Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

**I want to run deepzoom sample in windows 10.**

follow the:https://github.com/openslide/openslide-python#installation

```
1. Install OpenSlide.
2. pip install openslide-python
```

after I enter 2 in cmd, it shows:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Then I tried:https://www.scivision.dev/python-windows-visual-c-14-required/

```
1.install vs_buildtools.exe

2.install “Windows 10 SDK” in buildtool option

3.download OpenSlide Windows Binaries in https://openslide.org/download/#windows-binaries

4.add binaries path to system path
```

error remains.

all error log:

```
(venv) D:\Projects\Libs\openslide-python\examples\deepzoom>pip install openslide-python
Collecting openslide-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/5a/5b0adeabce81f018a9e4ffe9a419536064bc95c1b12194aff9b7e48f91f7/openslide-python-1.1.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in d:\projects\libs\openslide-python\examples\deepzoom\venv\lib\site-packages (from openslide-python) (5.4.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: openslide-python
  Building wheel for openslide-python (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command d:\projects\libs\openslide-python\examples\deepzoom\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\summy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ewobbsly\\openslide-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\summy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-egblanr_ --python-tag cp37:
  C:\Users\summy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ewobbsly\openslide-python\setup.py:23: DistDeprecationWarning: Features are deprecated and will be removed in a future version. See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/65.
    Extension('openslide._convert', ['openslide/_convert.c']),
  C:\Users\summy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\distutils\core.py:108: DistDeprecationWarning: Features are deprecated and will be removed in a future version. See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/65.
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\openslide
  copying openslide\deepzoom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\openslide
  copying openslide\lowlevel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\openslide
  copying openslide\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\openslide
  copying openslide\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\openslide
  running build_ext
  building 'openslide._convert' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for openslide-python
  Running setup.py clean for openslide-python
Failed to build openslide-python
Installing collected packages: openslide-python
  Running setup.py install for openslide-python ... error
    Complete output from command d:\projects\libs\openslide-python\examples\deepzoom\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\summy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ewobbsly\\openslide-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\summy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bz8keavu\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers d:\projects\libs\openslide-python\examples\deepzoom\venv\include\site\python3.7\openslide-python:
    C:\Users\summy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ewobbsly\openslide-python\setup.py:23: DistDeprecationWarning: Features are deprecated and will be removed in a future version. See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/65.
      Extension('openslide._convert', ['openslide/_convert.c']),
    C:\Users\summy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\distutils\core.py:108: DistDeprecationWarning: Features are deprecated and will be removed in a future version. See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/65.
      _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\openslide
    copying openslide\deepzoom.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\openslide
    copying openslide\lowlevel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\openslide
    copying openslide\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\openslide
    copying openslide\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\openslide
    running build_ext
    building 'openslide._convert' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "d:\projects\libs\openslide-python\examples\deepzoom\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\summy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ewobbsly\\openslide-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\summy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bz8keavu\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers d:\projects\libs\openslide-python\examples\deepzoom\venv\include\site\python3.7\openslide-python" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\summy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ewobbsly\openslide-python\
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467429/2268680 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45918595/2268680 this two thread solve my question