# Locust installation - Visual Studio failed with exit status 1181

Tags: python, visual-studio, command-line, locust

I'm trying to install [locust](https://locust.io/)  but when I run the command `pip install locust`, I have an error with Visual Studio I think.
I'm using Windows 10.

This is the error :

```
 LINK : fatal error LNK1181: impossible to open the entry file 'ws2_32.lib'
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
 ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
  Running setup.py clean for gevent
Failed to build gevent
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I've searched this problem on the web but I didn't find any solution.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: Which Python version are you running? What happens when you try to install it manually in a virtual environment? E.g. using `$ virtualenv foobar`, `$ source foobar/bin/activate` and `(foobar) $ pip install locust`?

Comment: Hey, I'm on Windows and I'm using python 3.7.6

Comment: Hi! Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858836/python-installing-clarifai-vs14-0-link-exe-failed-with-exit-status-1158 and see if that can help!

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same issue :'(

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Do you mean you tried the solution and it didnt help?

Comment: Exactly the problem stay the same and the solution didn't work for me

Comment: ok, that is too bad... Maybe try reinstalling VS BuildTools or something? The issue is unlikely to be specific to locust...

Comment: I have reinstalled Python, Build Tools, but I still have the issue :(