# Problem installing spaCy in windows 10 with pip

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pip, nlp, spacy

I tried to install **spaCy** on **windows 10**. I have **python 3.7.0**, also I install Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 14.0.

When I ran the following command:

> pip install -U spacy

I got the following error:

> Generating code  Finished generating code  LINK : fatal error LNK1158:
>   cannot run 'rc.exe'  error: command 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe' failed with
>   exit status 1158

Any idea is there something I missing?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Either follow theses steps [Python, installing clarifai --> VS14.0 link.exe failed with exit status 1158](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858836/python-installing-clarifai-vs14-0-link-exe-failed-with-exit-status-1158) 
or install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and then run `conda install -c conda-forge spacy`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried that solution but it does not work for me. The problem is that spaCy is compatible with 64-bit python. After using 64-bit python instead of a 32-bit python one on Windows fixed that issue for me. (see
 https://github.com/explosion/spaCy#supports )