# error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158

Tags: python, git, pip, python-import

I am trying to run [astroalign](https://pypi.org/project/astroalign/) and I while executing one of the function of the astroalign.py file, it generated an exception "Type Error" and was catched in try-catch block. 
On debugging I figured it stopped execution inside one of the function named "_find_sources()" which had a import statement.

```
import sep
```

So I figured that I didn't had sep installed in my Pycharm Environment. On using internal feature to add libraries, It generated an error so I manually git cloned the library and executed `python setup.py install`. and I got an error.

Link(Error msg in doc files(Sorry couldn't fit in the body)): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fIetGXjsKCkx0RpDjiicHFMuC5wOkAv6pvmw5FmIFfs/edit?usp=sharing

I even tried using pip but ended up into same error:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
```

I specifically searched for `error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158` but no results found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858836/python-installing-clarifai-vs14-0-link-exe-failed-with-exit-status-1158 ?

Comment: Thanks mate. @CristiFati

Comment: If it's the same problem, then you can mark your question as a duplicate to that one.