# Cannot install fuzzy python 3.8 on windows 10

Tags: pip, python-3.8, fuzzy

I got this error when I try to install fuzzy in python 3.8 on windows 10
I had installed visual C++ 14.0 and windows 10 SDK
Any help please

The command : `pip install Fuzzy`
The error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\yazan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Yazan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fi25d2at\\Fuzzy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Yazan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fi25d2at\\Fuzzy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Yazan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-krmjs_a6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Yazan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fi25d2at\Fuzzy\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    cythoning src/fuzzy.pyx to src\fuzzy.c
    c:\users\yazan\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-fi25d2at\fuzzy\.eggs\cython-3.0a5-py3.8.egg\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:344: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using '3str' for now (Py3). This has changed from earlier releases! File: C:\Users\Yazan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fi25d2at\Fuzzy\src\fuzzy.pyx
      tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
    building 'fuzzy' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\yazan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\yazan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" /Tcsrc\fuzzy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src\fuzzy.obj
    fuzzy.c
    src\fuzzy.c(2842): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src\fuzzy.c(3176): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src\fuzzy.c(3527): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src\fuzzy.c(4020): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\yazan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\yazan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" /Tcsrc/double_metaphone.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src/double_metaphone.obj
    double_metaphone.c
    src/double_metaphone.c(26): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/double_metaphone.c(33): warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable 
deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\string.h(344): note: see declaration of 'strncpy'
    src/double_metaphone.c(172): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/double_metaphone.c(178): warning C4996: 'strcat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
    src/double_metaphone.c(195): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
    src/double_metaphone.c(255): error C2001: newline in constant
    src/double_metaphone.c(256): error C2146: syntax error: missing ':' before identifier 'MetaphAdd'
    src/double_metaphone.c(810): error C2001: newline in constant
    src/double_metaphone.c(811): error C2146: syntax error: missing ':' before identifier 'current'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\yazan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Yazan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fi25d2at\\Fuzzy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Yazan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-fi25d2at\\Fuzzy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Yazan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-krmjs_a6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Similar issues occurring for fuzzy.c with following configuration: pip 20.1.1 from C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: Do you also get error messages like the following?
 src/fuzzy.c(1330): error C2078: too many initializers
 src/fuzzy.c(1358): error C2099: initializer is not a constant
 src/fuzzy.c(1635): error C2198: 'PyCode_New': too few arguments for call

Comment: After all I installed fuzzy_matcher 
Then I've got a similar error, but I solved it like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563421/9154326