# Failed to install autopy

Tags: python

i have some problem when i was installing autopy.

i tried to install follow "https://github.com/autopilot-rs/autopy".

First i installed "rustup" and then open Window Shellpower to run as following

```
rustup default nightly-2019-10-05 (Changed up to date).
pip install -U setuptools-rust
pip install -U autopy
```

Then used the code :

```
pip install autopy
```

Then i got a very long error. i don't know how to fix it. i tried for a several solution but still got failed. Please anyone help me :(

```
**C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install autopy
Collecting autopy
  Using cached autopy-4.0.0.tar.gz (20 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: autopy
  Building wheel for autopy (setup.py) ... error**
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-op4bkdec\\autopy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-op4bkdec\\autopy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-7vdod5lh'
       cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\
  Complete output (107 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib
  creating build\lib\autopy
  copying autopy\__init__.py -> build\lib\autopy
  running build_ext
  running build_rust
      Updating crates.io index
  cargo rustc --lib --manifest-path Cargo.toml --features pyo3/extension-module --release --verbose -- --crate-type cdylib
     Compiling autocfg v1.0.1
     Compiling const_fn v0.4.2
     Compiling proc-macro2 v0.4.30
     Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
     Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
     Compiling libc v0.2.80
       Running `rustc --crate-name autocfg C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\autocfg-1.0.1\src\lib.rs --color never --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=35f92dd5022e4db3 -C extra-filename=-35f92dd5022e4db3 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
       Running `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\proc-macro2-0.4.30\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"proc-macro\"" -C metadata=2a9a411cff140746 -C extra-filename=-2a9a411cff140746 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\proc-macro2-2a9a411cff140746 -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
       Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name cfg_if C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cfg-if-1.0.0\src\lib.rs --color never --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=03169066d99648e9 -C extra-filename=-03169066d99648e9 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
       Running `rustc --crate-name lazy_static C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\lazy_static-1.4.0\src\lib.rs --color never --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=225660f335b8510b -C extra-filename=-225660f335b8510b --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
       Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\const_fn-0.4.2\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=e902572d4f8d681e -C extra-filename=-e902572d4f8d681e --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\const_fn-e902572d4f8d681e -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
       Running `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\libc-0.2.80\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"std\"" -C metadata=c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 -C extra-filename=-c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\libc-c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
     Compiling memchr v2.3.3
       Running `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\memchr-2.3.3\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"std\"" --cfg "feature=\"use_std\"" -C metadata=4028d0d82ef1756a -C extra-filename=-4028d0d82ef1756a --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\memchr-4028d0d82ef1756a -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
     Compiling unicode-xid v0.1.0
       Running `rustc --crate-name unicode_xid C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\unicode-xid-0.1.0\src\lib.rs --color never --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" -C metadata=ab371f9fa6c950cc -C extra-filename=-ab371f9fa6c950cc --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
     Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.24
       Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\proc-macro2-1.0.24\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"proc-macro\"" -C metadata=175f24cebcdec8e2 -C extra-filename=-175f24cebcdec8e2 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\proc-macro2-175f24cebcdec8e2 -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
  error: linker `link.exe` not found
    |
    = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

  note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

  note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option

  error: aborting due to previous error

  error: Could not compile `memchr`.

  Caused by:
    process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\memchr-2.3.3\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"std\"" --cfg "feature=\"use_std\"" -C metadata=4028d0d82ef1756a -C extra-filename=-4028d0d82ef1756a --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\memchr-4028d0d82ef1756a -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1)
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
  error: linker `link.exe` not found
    |
    = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

  note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

  note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option

  error: aborting due to previous error

  error: Could not compile `libc`.

  Caused by:
    process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\libc-0.2.80\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"std\"" -C metadata=c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 -C extra-filename=-c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\libc-c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1)
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
  error: linker `link.exe` not found
    |
    = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

  note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

  note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option

  error: aborting due to previous error

  error: Could not compile `proc-macro2`.

  Caused by:
    process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\proc-macro2-0.4.30\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"proc-macro\"" -C metadata=2a9a411cff140746 -C extra-filename=-2a9a411cff140746 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\proc-macro2-2a9a411cff140746 -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1)
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
  error: linker `link.exe` not found
    |
    = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

  note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

  note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option

  error: aborting due to previous error

  error: Could not compile `const_fn`.

  Caused by:
    process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\const_fn-0.4.2\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=e902572d4f8d681e -C extra-filename=-e902572d4f8d681e --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\const_fn-e902572d4f8d681e -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1)
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
  error: linker `link.exe` not found
    |
    = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

  note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

  note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option

  error: aborting due to previous error

  error: Could not compile `proc-macro2`.

  Caused by:
    process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\proc-macro2-1.0.24\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"proc-macro\"" -C metadata=175f24cebcdec8e2 -C extra-filename=-175f24cebcdec8e2 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\proc-macro2-175f24cebcdec8e2 -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1)
  warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
  error: build failed
  error: cargo failed with code: 101

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for autopy
  Running setup.py clean for autopy
Failed to build autopy
Installing collected packages: autopy
    Running setup.py install for autopy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-op4bkdec\\autopy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-op4bkdec\\autopy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mfrgjlaj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\autopy'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\
    Complete output (91 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\autopy
    copying autopy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\autopy
    running build_ext
    running build_rust
    cargo rustc --lib --manifest-path Cargo.toml --features pyo3/extension-module --release --verbose -- --crate-type cdylib
       Compiling const_fn v0.4.2
       Compiling autocfg v1.0.1
       Compiling proc-macro2 v0.4.30
       Compiling libc v0.2.80
       Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
       Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
         Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\const_fn-0.4.2\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=e902572d4f8d681e -C extra-filename=-e902572d4f8d681e --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\const_fn-e902572d4f8d681e -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
         Running `rustc --crate-name autocfg C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\autocfg-1.0.1\src\lib.rs --color never --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=35f92dd5022e4db3 -C extra-filename=-35f92dd5022e4db3 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
         Running `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\proc-macro2-0.4.30\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"proc-macro\"" -C metadata=2a9a411cff140746 -C extra-filename=-2a9a411cff140746 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\proc-macro2-2a9a411cff140746 -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
         Running `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\libc-0.2.80\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"std\"" -C metadata=c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 -C extra-filename=-c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\libc-c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
         Running `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name cfg_if C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cfg-if-1.0.0\src\lib.rs --color never --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=03169066d99648e9 -C extra-filename=-03169066d99648e9 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
         Running `rustc --crate-name lazy_static C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\lazy_static-1.4.0\src\lib.rs --color never --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=225660f335b8510b -C extra-filename=-225660f335b8510b --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
       Compiling scopeguard v1.1.0
         Running `rustc --crate-name scopeguard C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\scopeguard-1.1.0\src\lib.rs --color never --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"use_std\"" -C metadata=e89bfb345c92a91e -C extra-filename=-e89bfb345c92a91e --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
       Compiling unicode-xid v0.1.0
         Running `rustc --crate-name unicode_xid C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\unicode-xid-0.1.0\src\lib.rs --color never --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" -C metadata=ab371f9fa6c950cc -C extra-filename=-ab371f9fa6c950cc --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
       Compiling memchr v2.3.3
         Running `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\memchr-2.3.3\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"std\"" --cfg "feature=\"use_std\"" -C metadata=4028d0d82ef1756a -C extra-filename=-4028d0d82ef1756a --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\memchr-4028d0d82ef1756a -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow`
    error: linker `link.exe` not found
      |
      = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

    note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

    note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option

    error: aborting due to previous error

    error: Could not compile `libc`.

    Caused by:
      process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\libc-0.2.80\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"std\"" -C metadata=c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 -C extra-filename=-c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\libc-c4d1b3eb8f1b8522 -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1)
    warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
    error: linker `link.exe` not found
      |
      = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

    note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

    note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option

    error: aborting due to previous error

    error: Could not compile `proc-macro2`.

    Caused by:
      process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\proc-macro2-0.4.30\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"proc-macro\"" -C metadata=2a9a411cff140746 -C extra-filename=-2a9a411cff140746 --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\proc-macro2-2a9a411cff140746 -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1)
    warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
    error: linker `link.exe` not found
      |
      = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

    note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

    note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option

    error: aborting due to previous error

    error: linker `link.exe` not found
      |
      = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

    note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

    note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option

    error: aborting due to previous error

    error: Could not compile `const_fn`.

    Caused by:
      process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --edition=2018 --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\const_fn-0.4.2\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C metadata=e902572d4f8d681e -C extra-filename=-e902572d4f8d681e --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\const_fn-e902572d4f8d681e -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1)
    warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
    error: Could not compile `memchr`.

    Caused by:
      process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name build_script_build C:\Users\user\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\memchr-2.3.3\build.rs --color never --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 --cfg "feature=\"default\"" --cfg "feature=\"std\"" --cfg "feature=\"use_std\"" -C metadata=4028d0d82ef1756a -C extra-filename=-4028d0d82ef1756a --out-dir C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\build\memchr-4028d0d82ef1756a -L dependency=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-op4bkdec\autopy\target\release\deps --cap-lints allow` (exit code: 1)
    warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
    error: build failed
    error: cargo failed with code: 101

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-op4bkdec\\autopy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-op4bkdec\\autopy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mfrgjlaj\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\autopy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: does this answer your [question](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858836/python-installing-clarifai-vs14-0-link-exe-failed-with-exit-status-1158&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjuiriPzdLsAhWpSRUIHUg1BpAQFjAAegQICxAB&usg=AOvVaw37Pl2ZCkM7J7V5_r5xPNer)

Answer (score 0):

Create "virtualenv" folder with python version 3.7.0 and run the command

```
pip install autopy
```