# Having trouble pip installing dulwich=0.20.25

Tags: python, pycharm, dulwich

Trying to run a web application via Pycharm. I needed Microsoft Visual Studio Build 2015, so I downloaded it and now I'm trying to run the code after having just installed it. I need Dulwich 0.20.25, but I get the following errors when I do `pip install dulwich==0.20.25`:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\hannmar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users
\\hannmar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-ec5rnowp\\dulwich_bbdf9b914bb64c6b876cc372fe9b8095\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\hannmar\\AppData\\Local
\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-ec5rnowp\\dulwich_bbdf9b914bb64c6b876cc372fe9b8095\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__
file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file
__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hannmar\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-record-6llj_6vs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
 --install-headers 'c:\users\hannmar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Include\dulwich'
         cwd: C:\Users\hannmar\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-ec5rnowp\dulwich_bbdf9b914bb64c6b876cc372fe9b8095\
    Complete output (309 lines):
    c:\users\hannmar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\dulwich
    copying dulwich\archive.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\dulwich
    copying dulwich\bundle.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\dulwich
    copying dulwich\cli.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\dulwich
    copying dulwich\client.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\dulwich
...

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\hannmar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36
-32\include -Ic:\users\hannmar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program F
iles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows K
its\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.
0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" /Tcdulwich/_objects.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\dulwich/_objects.obj
    _objects.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\h
annmar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\hannmar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Ki
ts\10\lib\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0
.17763.0\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit__objects build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\dulwich/_objects.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.6\dulwich\_objects.cp36-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\t
emp.win32-3.6\Release\dulwich\_objects.cp36-win32.lib
       Creating library build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\dulwich\_objects.cp36-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\dulwich\_objects.cp36-win32.exp
    Generating code
    Finished generating code
    LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\hannmar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, token
ize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\hannmar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-ec5rnowp\\dulwich_bbdf9b914bb64c6b876cc372fe9b8095\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C
:\\Users\\hannmar\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\1\\pip-install-ec5rnowp\\dulwich_bbdf9b914bb64c6b876cc372fe9b8095\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', ope
n)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.
close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\hannmar\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-record-6llj_6vs\install-record.txt' --single-ver
sion-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hannmar\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Include\dulwich' Check the logs for full command ou
tput.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you edit in the whole traceback, not the truncated version?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error on windows 10 using a python 3.8 installation. Which version of python are you using in pycharm?

Comment: @C.Nivs The traceback is too long to include the whole thing, but I edited my post with more of it. I'm using Python 3.6.0 with Pycharm.

Comment: Maybe this answer helps:
[VS14.0 link.exe failed with exit status 1158](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858836/python-installing-clarifai-vs14-0-link-exe-failed-with-exit-status-1158)